# How to wrap select query into one alias

Tags: mysql

I use the same select query twice. How can I change this into one query or alias?

My code:

```
select * 
from 
(
    select store, count(*) as quantity 
    from bbb
    where MONTH(date) = 12
    group by store
) as december
having quantity = (select MAX(maxi) 
                from
                (
                    select store, count(*) as maxi 
                    from bbb 
                    where MONTH(date) = 12
                    group by store) as december 
                )
```

Comment: there should be quantity

Comment: That `count` is empty :$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a single top-counting store, use this:

```
SELECT  store, COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM    bbb
WHERE   MONTH(datE) = 12
GROUP BY
        store
ORDER BY
        quantity DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Unlike your original query, this one will not return possible ties though.

Comment: @kaszkietoo: may I ask what is the reason for this?

Comment: It's a request from my geek :)